# Citrix/COTS application monitor - Splunk

Tags: splunk, citrix, xendesktop, cots

Our COTS applications are configured on Citrix, is it possible to monitor COTS apps via Splunk?

Answer (score 0):

Do either of the [Citrix](https://splunkbase.splunk.com/apps/#/search/citrix) [XenDesktop](https://splunkbase.splunk.com/apps/#/search/xendesktop) [Splunkbase](https://splunkbase.splunk.com) apps do what you're looking for?

- Splunk App for Citrix XenDesktop - https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/994/#/details
- Template for Citrix XenDesktop 7 - https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/1751/#/overview